# How to Insert key- value pair in a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$totalAgeChecks[] = (
        [0] => Array
               (
                [AgeCheck] => 0
               )
        [1] => Array
              (
               [AgeCheck] => 1
              )
       )
```

I want to insert another value with each element so that the final array becomes like this

```
$totalAgeChecks[] = (
         [0] => Array
                (
                  [AgeCheck] => 0
                  [AgeCheckValue] => No
                 )
         [1] => Array
                (
                 [AgeCheck] => 1
                 [AgeCheckValue] => Yes
                )
         )
```

What function shall I use/ How to achieve that?
i want to do it with foreach loop like following. But what function shall I use so the the correct data is inserted in the correct position?

I have tried

```
foreach ($totalAgeChecks as $key => $row) 
    {

        if ($totalAgeChecks[$key]['AgeCheck'] == 1)
        {
                $totalAgeChecks[$key]['AgeCheckValue'] = "Yes";
        }
        elseif($totalAgeChecks[$key]['AgeCheck'] == 0)
        {
                $totalAgeChecks[$key]['AgeCheckValue'] = "No";
        }
        
    }
```

Also

```
        foreach ($totalAgeChecks as $i => $value) {
        switch ($value) {
            case 0:
                $value['Name'] = 'No';
                break;
            case 1:
                $value['Name'] = 'yes';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach - you can make a new array and add to it as you go along.

```
$totalAgeChecks[] = [
        0 => [
                "AgeCheck" => 0
             ],
        1 => [
               "AgeCheck" => 1
             ],
       ];
    
$newArr = [];

foreach ($totalAgeChecks[0] as $key => $arr)
{
    $text = "";
    $newArr[] = [
        "AgeCheck" => $arr["AgeCheck"],
        "AgeCheckValue" => ($arr["AgeCheck"] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")
    ];
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["AgeCheck"]=>
    int(0)
    ["AgeCheckValue"]=>
    string(2) "No"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["AgeCheck"]=>
    int(1)
    ["AgeCheckValue"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://3v4l.org/qm6Wk

If you wanted to assign that back to `$totalAgeChecks` again afterwards you could of course easily do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
// loop your data array, in your case i'm assuming the data array is $totalAgeChecks[0]
foreach($totalAgeChecks[0] as &$row){   
    $row["AgeCheckValue"] = ($row["AgeCheck"] == 1 ? "Yes":"No");
}

// print result
var_dump($totalAgeChecks);
```

Answer (score 1):

In an associative array inserting new data work a little different:

```
$totalAgeChecks =array(
  ["AgeCheck" => 0],
  ["AgeCheck" => 1]
);
$x=0;
foreach($totalAgeChecks as $row){
   if($row['AgeCheck'] == 1)
   {
        $totalAgeChecks[$x] += array("AgeCheckValue" => "Yes");
    }
  elseif($row['AgeCheck'] == 0)
   {
         $totalAgeChecks[$x] += array("AgeCheckValue" => "No");
   }
   $x++;
}
```